# Geometric RSK correspondece and classical RSK correspondence

Tags: co.combinatorics

In the [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5126v2), geometric RSK correspondence is given by 
$$
\left( \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right) \mapsto \left( \begin{matrix} \frac{bc}{b+c} & ab \\ ac & \frac{ad}{b+c} \end{matrix} \right).
$$
How this map relates to the classical RSK correspondence? Thank you very much.

Edit: the map is
$$
\left( \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right) \mapsto \left( \begin{matrix} \frac{bc}{b+c} & ab \\ ac & ad(b+c) \end{matrix} \right).
$$

Comment: Related http://mathoverflow.net/questions/97899

Comment: A note -- if you're linking to arXiv, it's better to link to the abstract (http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.5126v2) rather than directly to the PDF. From the abstract, one can easily click through to the PDF; not so the reverse. And the abstract allows one to do things like see different versions of the paper, search for other things by the same authors, etc.  Thank you!

Comment: @HarryAltman, thank you very much. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have some notes that hopefully explain some of this: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~shopkins/docs/rsk.pdf.

By the way, I believe you got the map slightly wrong. It should be:
$$
\left( \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right) \mapsto \left( \begin{matrix} \frac{bc}{b+c} & ab \\ ac & ad(b+c) \end{matrix} \right).
$$
See Example 7 from the above linked notes to see why the tropicalized version of this map
$$
\left( \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} \right) \mapsto \left( \begin{matrix} \mathrm{min}(b,c) & a+b \\ a+c & a+d+\mathrm{max}(b,c) \end{matrix} \right)
$$
is classical RSK in disguise. I should say I learned all of this material from Alex Postnikov.

Comment: I think this goes back to Kirillov-Berenstein, http://www.mathnet.ru/links/15a3ee0a7fd583443105a1df4a75546e/aa491.pdf
See page 101, where this type of toggles are introduced.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: indeed; that paper is cited in the linked notes.